# Apache Camel - JSONPath expressions to fetch multiple values

Tags: apache-camel, jsonpath

In a camel route need to read values from an incoming json data through rest client. Using JsonPath to parse and get the values from it.

The expression used to fetch the json data works for one value and not for the other.

The JSON data incoming form the rest client:

`[{"var1": 10,"var2": 20}]`

JSONPath expression used inside the camel route:

```
                <setHeader headerName="data1">
                    <jsonpath suppressExceptions="true">$[0].var1</jsonpath>
                </setHeader>
               <log message="value1 : ${header.data1}" />

                <setHeader headerName="data2">
                    <jsonpath suppressExceptions="true">$[0].var2</jsonpath>
                </setHeader>
               <log message="valu2 : ${header.data2}" />
```

Can see the value getting logged in the first logger, but the second logger is 'null' and camel throws an 'NullPointerException'.

**Question:**

Can some one guide me if this is the right json path expression to get the values. If not do guide me to a solution.

Have checked the expressions working and returning values using various online tools available for json path.

Comment: Did you enable stream caching?

Comment: Yeah could be that, see this FAQ: http://camel.apache.org/why-is-my-message-body-empty.html

Comment: @Ralf - ya it was due to stream caching only..enabled it on the route and now its working.

Comment: @ClausIbsen - thank u too for the link which led to all the info about stream caching and its options..realy thanx

Comment: can anyone of you post this as an answer so that I can except it for others to know it.

Comment: Yeah Ralf posted the answer first, he should be welcome to post that as an answer, and possible add links to the FAQ and/or the stream-caching link as well